# Mongo timeout from jenkins build

Tags: java, mongodb, jenkins

I have a jenkins pipeline which runs Junit test cases and then runs sonar.
Test cases are failing with below mongo timeout exception. Basically ,jenkins slave unable to connect to mongodb.  MongoDB is running on a container.

```
     Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: 
Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}]
```

Here is my servicebundle yaml where the container config is present

```
mongo:
    image: mongo:3.4.22-xenial
    container_name: mongo_dbc
    hostname: mongdb_host
    expose:
      - "27017"
    networks:
      vpcbr:
        ipv4_address: 172.172.x.x
```

Code:

```
String mongoIpAddress = "172.172.x.x"
        int mongoPort = 27017;
        InputStream istream = null;
        FileOutputStream outStream=null;
            if(mongoDBContainer == null) {
                mongoDBContainer = new MongoDBContainer(DockerImageName.parse("mongo:3.4.22-xenial")).withExposedPorts(27017);
                mongoDBContainer.start();
                mongoIpAddress = mongoDBContainer.getContainerIpAddress();
            }
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong.